# RecyclerView for firebase crud

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm new to android programming and I am trying to create a project in Android Studio using Java.
The main goal it is to do simple CRUD tasks and use Firebase as realtime database.

I've already configured the build.gradle with plugin and all the dependencies

**dependencies**:

```
`apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.1.0')
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.6.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

Then i created the model classes: company:

```
public class Company {
public String name;
public String email;
public String website;
public String key;

public Company()
{}

public Company(String name, String email, String website, String key) {
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.website = website;
    this.key = key;


   }

public String getName() { return name;}

public void setName(String name) { this.name = name;}

public String getEmail() { return email;}

public void setEmail(String email) { this.email = email;}

public String getWebsite() { return website;}

public void setWebsite(String website) { this.website = website;}

public String getKey() { return key;}

public void setKey(String key) { this.key = key;}}
```

**local class:**

```
public class Local {

private String name;
private String address;
private String description;
private String key;

public Local(String name, String address, String description,String key) {
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    this.description = description;
    this.key = key;
}

public Local() {}

public Local(String name, String address, String description) {
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    this.description = description;
}

public String getName() { return name;}

public void setName(String name) { this.name = name;}

public String getAddress() { return address;}

public void setAddress(String address) { this.address = address;}

public String getDescription() {return description;}

public void setDescription(String description) { this.description = description;}

public String getKey() { return key;}

public void setKey(String key) { this.key = key;}}
```

I have another Employee class but it is similar to this two.
Then i started to figure it out, what could be the best approach to design my UI data.

**My question is**:

> Can I use more than one recyclerView in the project? I mean for every
> model class that i have, use one recyclerView.  If not, can you help
> me with a better implementation idea?

Thank you

Comment: Yes, you can use more than one recycler view. your model class is like a DB blueprint and Recycler View is more related to your UI. It's up to you to decide the number of recycler view that is required.

Comment: What do you mean by "what could be the best approach to design my UI data"?